# Yii2 Security, permission changed and error

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have a page on Yii2, it worked without problems.
But the Hosting changed the permissions due to attacks to the server, I can not even execute `phpinfo();` And I get the following error `"Unable to generate a random key"`
If I delete `<? = Html :: csrfMetaTags ()?>` It works fine even though Login does not work for me.
It is also not the idea to delete `<? = Html :: csrfMetaTags ()?>`

Any alternative?

I was told I could create a folder inside the hosting and assign permissions so that "others" can write and read, but how do you do that?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Need more info about error as on screen

Comment: Its not clear. What is exception?

Comment: @YasarArafath The exception is the Security, "Unable to generate a random key", the system don't can create a random key, it worked without problems. But the Hosting changed the permissions due to attacks to the server, I now not worked, but if i delete line"<? = Html :: csrfMetaTags ()?>"  this worked, but any alternative? disable random keys? etc.

Comment: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/10519#issuecomment-168710732